# Remove margin and padding from html and body elements in Vue?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I've got a project I created with the `vue init webpack my-project` cli command.

This is my `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and my `App.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <div id="text">{{ text }}</div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">

.html, .body {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}

#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
}

#text {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 50%;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

</style>
```

I run my site with `npm run dev` and when I inspect element on Chrome, I see that the `<body>` class has a margin:

[image: Margin in body from inspect element]

I want to eliminate all margin and padding from the `<html>` and `<body>` elements but what I've got doesn't seem to be working.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no such thing as `lang=scss`. SCSS won't run in the browser.

Comment: @Rob That tells Vue to compile SCSS files when Webpack runs. Its completely valid in that context.

Comment: @BryceHowitson Interesting.

Comment: does SCSS or Vue treat `.html, .body` as classes instead of tags?

Comment: SCSS compiles to CSS so yes anything prepended with a period are considered class names. Hence the reason this didn't work. `body` & `html` are tag names not classes so the browser ignored those classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace your scss to this:

```
<style lang="scss">

html, body {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Upd:

Just to be more clear for future visitors. As noticed in comments, you have `.html` and `.body` which is referenced to css classes which is absent in your html code.

Comment: Also consider to use a reset css.

Comment: @Sfili_81 a reset is rarely if ever needed.

Comment: @MikeFaber `html` and `body` are tags, not classes